# (ERC721) Is my mint() function guaranteed to mint consecutive tokenIDs for each user who calls it?

Tags: evm, nft, erc-721, mint, reentrant-attacks

It is great to see a supportive community that could potentially help me out. I hope my question (as a beginner blockchain dev) is not too basic.

I have the following mint() function (users can call it, so I am implementing lazy minting) that uses OpenZeppelin's _safemint() in my ERC721 contract:

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
   uint256 supply = totalSupply();
   require(!paused);
   require(_mintAmount > 0);
   require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
   require(_mintAmount%4==0);
   require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

   if (msg.sender != owner()) {
     require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
   }

   for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
     _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
     //the following line is actually a bit more sophisticated in my actual code and serves an 
     //actual purpose, I have simplified it here to show that a boolean gets pushed to an array 
     isRevealed.push(false);
}
```

}

The specific collection that I am building requires that:

- users mint in multiples of 4 or doesn't mint any NFTs at all
- each user who calls (transacts with) the mint function above gets consecutive tokenIDs - e.g. 1,2,3,4 or 5,6,7,8.

A user should never:

- get non-consecutive tokenIDs, e.g. 1,2,3,5
- mint some number other than 0 and a multiple of 4, for example - 2 NFTs - tokenIDs 1 and 2, for example
- Mint four consecutive tokenIDs with a beginning tokenID that is not 1, 5, 9, 13, etc. - e.g. tokenIDs 3,4,5 6. This would happen if for example someone before that only minted tokenIDs 1 and 2.

As far as I understand Ethereum transactions are atomic - either the whole transaction executes or none of it. So because of my "require(_mintAmount%4==0)" I am guessing that users will always be minting in multiples of 4 or 0 NFTs (please, correct me if I am wrong). However, I am concerned that:

- the mint() function could be executing concurrently for many users and mint 4 non-consecutive tokenIDs for each user; on one hand I read that the EVM is single-threaded, so only one person could be in mint() at a time, on the other hand - don't reentrancy attacks exist exactly because it is possible to enter a function before it has stopped executing a previous call to it? I must be missing something (again, I am a beginner)
- there is another way that I am unaware of (an "unknown unknown" kind of problem) that the function will exhibit one of the unwanted behaviors listed above, for example mint only two tokenIDs during some call - then this will not only be an issue for this user, but for all users, and the whole project will be ruined. The project depends on every user getting exactly 4 consecutive IDs, exactly from tokenID 1.

Do you think this function will satisfy the behavior that I am looking for? If not, can you think of possible fixes? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function should work as expected. Since the Blockchain is single-thread there will never be a concurrent execution of this function (as transactions go one after another). If you need to be sure some unforseen case will not break your contract, add `assure(supply % 4 == 0)` at the end of the function. If for some reason function finished with the incorrect amount minted, it will revert all the changes.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that was the case but I wasn't 100% sure. Great idea with the assure check at the end as well. After I posted, I read on how reentrancy attacks work and realized that they need an external call to work & don't break single-threadedness, and as far as I see the code in _safemint(), it just updates internal arrays. So now everything seems much more clear. Thank you.

Comment: What is `assure`? Do you mean `assert`? Further, the `supply` variable doesn't change so why wouldn't you use `assert(totalSupply() == supply + _mintAmount)` ?